# using swiper (or some similar library) to scroll a half screen width

Tags: javascript, html, touch, swipe

I'm currently developing a mobile app using swiper.js ([this one](http://idangero.us/swiper/#.WaNYoj7focU), as there seem to be multiple libraries of that name).  I'm trying to figure out how to set it up so that for one of its slides, it only scrolls the screen half a width.  There's a [demo](http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/32-slideable-menu.html) that does something *similar* to what I want, which suggests to me it should be possible, but I can't figure out how to make it work.

To give you more precise details, what I want is to have a layout that looks like this:

```
 +----+ +-----------+ +-----------+
 |    | | +---+---+ | |           |
 |    | | |   |   | | |           |
 |  A | | | B | C | | |     D     |
 |    | | |   |   | | |           |
 |    | | +---+---+ | |           |
 +----+ +-----------+ +-----------+
```

and I want to be able to use swipe gestures so that the viewport can be positioned in any of the following ways:

```
+-------------+
|+----+ +-----+-----+ +-----------+
||    | | +---+---+ | |           |
||    | | |   |   | | |           |
||  A | | | B | C | | |     D     |
||    | | |   |   | | |           |
||    | | +---+---+ | |           |
|+----+ +-----+-----+ +-----------+
+-------------+

       +-------------+
 +----+|+-----+-----+|+-----------+
 |    ||| +---+---+ |||           |
 |    ||| |   |   | |||           |
 |  A ||| | B | C | |||     D     |
 |    ||| |   |   | |||           |
 |    ||| +---+---+ |||           |
 +----+|+-----+-----+|+-----------+
       +-------------+

                     +-------------+
 +----+ +-----+-----+|+-----------+|
 |    | | +---+---+ |||           ||
 |    | | |   |   | |||           ||
 |  A | | | B | C | |||     D     ||
 |    | | |   |   | |||           ||
 |    | | +---+---+ |||           ||
 +----+ +-----+-----+|+-----------+|
                     +-------------+
```

I managed to get the first two view configurations working right by changing the style settings to remove the `width: 100%` on the `swiper-slide` class and using the `slidesPerView: "auto"` configuration setting, but then swiping right from the second view leaves the screen showing C and half of D, and you couldn't swipe any further so you couldn't get all of D into view.

How can I get this to work?  I'm not averse to switching to a different library if absolutely necessary.

Comment: Add a basic example (jsfiddle/snippet) that other people can play with... no one will just build this for you, however with a basic structure it will be much easier to find the problem and suggest a solution.

Comment: @Dekel - I'm working on one, but it's taking a while extracting the relevant bits out of a rather large app...

Comment: I'm sure it can take time. Next time I suggest that you open the question once you have everything you need for it :) Exactly the same as you took the time to create the ascii samples, a snippet is pretty much a requirement in this case :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the answer was pretty much exactly what I was initially expecting to work:

```js
var swiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
    slidesPerView: "auto"
  });
```

```css
.swiper-container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
}   
.swiper-slide {
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.swiper-slide > div { 
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.2/css/swiper.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.2/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Slider main container -->
<div class="swiper-container">
    <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <!-- Slides -->
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="width:150px">A</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" style="display:flex; flex-flow: row nowrap">
           <div style="flex-grow: 1">B</div><div style="flex-grow: 1">C</div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">D</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The only reason I failed to get this to work immediately was because I was using a wrapper for the library to integrate it with React, and this was creating an extra div that meant my settings weren't correctly overriding the default width.